# How to change kernel defconfig between different recipes

Tags: kernel, yocto, bitbake

I have two image recipes which build image files.

I want to use different kernel defconfig in those recipes.

I will create two kernel defconfig(A.defconfig and B.defconfig)

Example:

A recipe uses A.defconfig kernel defconfig.

B recipe uses B.defconfig kernel defconfig.

A and B kernel defconfig in kernel recipe and use same kernel version.

How to modify those recipes?

Thank you

John

Comment: A solution, but probably not the best one, is to use the PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel 'https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_PROVIDER'.  But you have to have two kernel recipes for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it. Thank you.